# BundleTable.EnableOptimizations doesn't work asp mvc

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have very strange problem in MVC BundleConfig file. Before publishing my site I set BundleTable.EnableOptimizations to true, and was waiting that my css file would be minimized after publishing. But one file from ScriptBundle is minified, and another one from same ScriptBundle isn't. Here is what I mean:

my BundleConfig code:

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/Site.css"));

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

and in _Layout I have:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

So result of this code is that, when I check sources of site in browser, there is one css file, where my bootstrap.css and Site.css files are combined, but bootstrap.css is minified, and Site.css isn't. I just can't figure out why system doesn't minifies my Site.css file.

It's the weirdest problem I had ever had, so if you know what's going on, please help me.

Comment: It could be a syntax error in the Site.css so that the minification fails. Can you run the css through http://csslint.net/ or some other validator?

Comment: Please read different between bundle and minfiy. then you find out your answer.

Comment: There was not any major syntax error in my css file @Esko, but that might be problem in other case, so thanks for feedback anyway!

Comment: Thank for advise @Surajghosi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try the following code

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/Site.css"));

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

using IgnoreList you can bypass any already minified css that is not including in bundle ,because its already minified and mvc bundle will ignore it.
If this doesnt work you need to validate your css, you can use web essentials to validate your css.
Hope this helps.

Comment: your answer was brilliant! bundles.IgnoreList.Clear() does magic staff! Just can't thank you enough!